# Django 500 error: WSGIRequest object has no attribute 'scope'

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

When I deployed the application on the server using uwsgi, I got an error

```
AttributeError at /
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'scope'
```

There is no such problem on the local machine, everything works.

The part of code getting this error:

```
class UserActivityMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        activities = [activity for activity in ACTIVITIES if re.match(activity['path'], request.scope.get('path'))
                      and activity['method'] == request.scope['method']]
        if activities:
                 .....
```

Comment: Where did `scope` come from?

Comment: Its looks like inner request method.

Comment: Neither Django's `HttpRequest` nor the original `WSGIRequest` classes have a property `scope`. So it's not clear why that would work in the first place.

Comment: Unless you had another custom middleware that added it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes I have extra middleware in my settings.py

Comment: When I remove middleware from setings, everything works. Thank you all, I'll deal with